# plotting of lines of regressionnof x on y and lines of regression of y on x in MS Excel

Tags: regression, excel

I have following data:
x:1 3 5 7 9
y:2 4 5 8 12

I want to plot lines of regression of y on x as well as lines of regression of x on y on the same graph in MS excel. I tried bit it gives only line of regression of y on x.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To get $y$ as a function of $x,$ you first select the $x$ column (including the label cell), then hold down Ctrl while you do the same for the $y$ column. Insert the graph, ask for a trendline, display the $R^2$ value and the equation, and you're done. Then you have to add data to the graph. Right-click the graph and use Select Data... You can add another series, selecting the appropriate $x$ and $y$ columns. Then add a trendline to that as well.